# Magento 2 adminhtml directory missing from app/design/

Tags: magento-2.1, adminhtml

I have a `Magento ver. 2.1.8` install and realised that there is no `app/design/adminhtml` directory.

I realised that after trying to `setup:static-content:deploy` as I got this error:

```
Compilation from source:
adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/css/styles.less
Unable to get content for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Checkout/css/source/module/_checkout.less'
```

So tried to find the directory but it is not there... Should I be worried? Download and upload any files there?

Comment: By default, the folder for `app/design/adminhtml` is empty, the style is taken from the `vendor` and for that error you should try to run if on developer mode `grunt exec:backend` , `grunt less:backend` and after that you should be ok. BTW it is not recomanded to run `static content deploy` on `Developer mode`, only on `Production mode`

Comment: I don't have a grunt installed on my CLI. What these commands do? Is it worth getting this installed?

Comment: grunt exec - fertches all the less files defined in a theme ( goes from the root less file in every @import and fetches a list of files to be compiled ), grunt less - does a compile of the files so the style is readable by the browser, turns variables into strings and so on. the static:content:deploy command does a compilation of the theme you suggest ( somehow what the 2 previous commands do )  you can read more here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_mode.html